# Strange JS issue while working with numeric values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sum, numeric

The idea is to refresh total value every time checkbox checked.

My HTML looks like that

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">


                                <tbody>
...
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="5" class="services"></td>
                                    <td>Sample</td>
                                     <td id="srv_5">60</td>
                                    </tr> 
 ...                    
</tbody>

                        </table>
```

Function looks like that

```
function calcServicesTotal() {
    var total=0;
    $('.services').each(function () {
        var id = parseInt($(this).val());
        var price = parseInt($("#srv_" + id).text());
        if (this.checked) {
            total = total + price;
            console.log("id - " + id + " price - " + price);
        }
        else {
            if (total > 0)
                total = total - price;
        }

    });
    console.log("total - " + total);
}
```

The problem is I can see `console.log("id - " + id + " price - " + price);` right values but total stays every time 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing `total - 60` in the Chrome console. Where is your code that calls `calcServicesTotal()`? You're possibly calling it too early, before the checkbox is recognised as being checked. Maybe make a JSFiddle?

Comment: @heron possibly zero is expected value by you logic?

Comment: Also, are you sure your `else` clause should be there? If the checkbox isn't currently checked, I agree that you don't want to **add** to `total`, but why would you want to **subtract** from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense

```
else {
    if (total > 0)
        total = total - price;
}
```

That else makes NO sense at all, so if the checkbox is unchecked, you subtract. So if the first checkbox is checked it will make total > 0 and  all checkboxes are unchecked, you start subtracting their values until it is zero.

That else check does not belong there.

Comment: so what's your solution?